# How to change the IP and port number for Asp core web app running with kestrel after publishing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, kestrel

I've searched a lot to find the answer for this question.

> How to change the IP and port number for Asp core app running with
>   kestrel?

As you know we build and debug AspCore apps with an address like this

> http://localhost:5000

But how to change It to something like this for accessing through the network after publishing:
**http://192.168.1.12:80** or more simpler since 80 is not necessary to be written **http://192.168.1.12** (80 is the default but other ports should be mentioned)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I could not find a complete step by step solution I share my experience with the community.

I hope It become helpful.

This is the answer :

In your server you should open **CMD** as **admin**

Then run this code :

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Http Port 80" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80
```

Next in your **appsettings.json** in your **publish folder** add these codes

```
"AllowedHosts": "*",
   "Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://192.168.1.12:80"
      }
    }
  }
```

Now your **appsettings.json** must become something like this :

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\;Database=MyDbName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
   "Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://192.168.1.12:80"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please consider that you can change **IP** and **Port number** the above are just samples.

And Also the Ip you are setting must be same as the server Ip Adderss.

you should change them there places:

- Http Port 80
- localport=80
- "Url": "http://192.168.1.12:80"

Now you can access this Ip through the network

> http://192.168.1.12:80 Or http://192.168.1.12